# How to put JavaScripts anywhere besides /public/javascripts in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 view (for my_controller#show) which has a lot of JavaScript.

I'd like to move that JavaScript to a separate `my_show.js` file and then include that file using Rails' `javascript_include_tag` method.  This works if I put `my_show.js` in the `/public/javascripts` directory.  But I'd prefer to put the file in the same directory with the view with which it's associated.

Is it possible to configure rails such that I can use `javascript_include_tag` to include files outside `/public/javascripts`?

My solution right now is to make a partial called `_my_show.html.haml`.  In this file I put my JavaScript code.  Then I include the file with `render`.

I'm wondering if there's a preferred Rails 3 way to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider creating a route for the js file.

```
get '/my_controller/show_js.js' => 'my_controller#show_js'
```

And put your js content in `views/my_controller/show_js.js.erb`

Now, you should be able to include your js file by:

```
javascript_include_tag "/my_controller/show_js.js"
```

Comment: I guess this would work, I just ended up putting all my files in /public/javascripts with sub-directories below that for organization.  At least this allows me to have plain .js files (not .js.erb files) and I don't have to add a route for each one of them.  I suppose there's a more clever way to do this but my solution works for now.

Answer (score 2):

[JAMMIT!](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/)

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming [Rails 3.1](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/5/22/rails-3-1-release-candidate) includes the [Sprockets gem](http://getsprockets.org/) to provide an Asset Pipeline feature that offers more flexibility in placement of JavaScript and other assets.

One can also use Sprockets independently of Rails 3.1.